# Solve a transcendental equation in C

Tags: c, math, equation

I need solve this transcendental equation in C:

x = 2.0 - 0.5sen(x)

I tried this:

```
double x, newx, delta;

x = 2.0 - 0.5; 
newx = sin(x);
delta = fabs(newx * x);

printf("%f", delta);
```

This is correct?

Thanks!

Comment: You are actually finding where `f(x) = x` intersects `g(x) = 2 - sin(x)/2`. You can draw this out to see the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to iterate the formula you have been given until it converges to the solution. This is the [fixed-point iteration method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration) for solving equations of the type `x = f(x)`.

```
#define TOLERANCE 1e-8
#define MAX_ITER 50

double solve_equation() {
    double x = 1.0; /* 1.0 is our initial guess */
    double x_old;
    int i = 0;      /* iteration counter */
    do {
        x_old = x;
        x = 2 - 0.5*sin(x); /* magic! */
        i++;
    } while (fabs(x-x_old)/x > TOLERANCE && i < MAX_ITER);

    return x;
}
```

In this particular case the method converges fast and the cap on the iteration count is unnecessary. The answer turns out to be 1.50121007326.

For general [root finding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) you'll probably find other algorithms more useful, such as the [bisection method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method), the [secant method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method), or [Newton's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) or [Halley's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halley%27s_method) methods.

Answer (score 2):

Use a numeric method to solve your equation, like [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) or (a lot easier to use, and not too much slower in practice) the [secant method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method). For the last one, *don't* rewrite the expression for the next x, it is written that way so that rounding errors (a problem near the root) don't affect too much.